# Is a pc behind a router visible to the net using ipv6?

Tags: ipv6

I've got a pc connected to the net behind a router, pretty standard stuff. I am wondering if any of the ipv6 addresses listed for my pc can be reached from the rest of the net. So far I've not had luck pinging or ssh'ing from a remote server (which does support ipv6 insofar as `ping ipv6.google.com` works, also true for my pc).  Both the pings and ssh hang.
Should any of these ipv6 addrs in principle be visible from the rest of the net?

```
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~/sw/tor-browser_en-US/Browser$ ifconfig
....    
wlp59s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.52  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 2a10:8006:1f6c:0:ad49:e1a3:327a:714c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::3ad4:73bf:e4b1:b2e2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fde5:3ccb:8b2:0:ad49:e1a3:327a:714c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fde5:3ccb:8b2:0:b67a:b275:d6b5:63af  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a10:8006:1f6c:0:7180:69bd:4b64:a3fd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 9c:b6:d0:13:98:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 367229  bytes 331829936 (331.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 256033  bytes 171040955 (171.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ssh from a remote machine hangs after

```
root@scrpr:~# ssh -vvvvv jeremy@2a10:8006:1f6c:0:7180:69bd:4b64:a3fd
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "2a10:8006:1f6c:0:7180:69bd:4b64:a3fd" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 2a10:8006:1f6c:0:7180:69bd:4b64:a3fd [2a10:8006:1f6c:0:7180:69bd:4b64:a3fd] port 22.
```

and /var/log/auth.log shows no activity.

I haven't touched the ufw rules since installing ubuntu 20.04, status says

```
jeremy@jeremy-Blade:~/sw/tor-browser_en-US/Browser$ sudo service ufw status
● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2021-07-03 19:53:55 EEST; 27min ago
       Docs: man:ufw(8)
    Process: 535 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 535 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Warning: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.
```

Comment: An important starting point is to list the active IPv6 rules for your firewall (IIRC `iptables6 -nvL`)

Comment: Can you ping any of your _router's_ IPv6 addresses from the remote server? Have you checked your router's IPv6 firewall rules?

Comment: yes it came down to a firewall on the router . @roaima tkx, the command is ip6tables it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no – the address is reachable by default, but a firewall can prevent it from being reachable.

(Seems to me that "visible *to* the net" doesn't mean the same thing as "reachable *from* the net" – they seem to be kind of opposites, at least in the sense that you're asking.)

If you have IPv6 at home, most likely your home router has its own firewall that only allows outbound connections (and responses) but blocks any inbound connections at the edge of the network. (And if you're using IPv6 at work or school, then it is even more likely that inbound access to the entire LAN is filtered by a firewall.)

Technically it's even possible that packets would be blocked at ISP level, affecting *all* customers (e.g. to 'encourage' them to pay for a business plan or something).

Run `tcpdump -n -i wlp59s0 ip6` or `wireshark -k -i wlp59s0 -f ip6` – this will show all IPv6 packets, even those that would be blocked by UFW or iptables. If this shows incoming pings, then the problem is your computer's firewall (i.e. UFW rules); if it shows incoming Neighbour Solicitations but *not* outgoing Neighbour Advertisements, the problem is either with your OS or with the actual address being wrong; and if it shows nothing at all, then it's definitely being blocked somewhere higher (i.e. on your router or ISP).

---

On Linux you should be using `ip addr` to check which IP addresses you have. The Linux 'ifconfig' is an old tool that often omits important information; it should be avoided. (This advice does not apply to BSDs, where ifconfig is the primary tool.)

In the 'ip addr' output, some of your IPv6 addresses may be marked "temporary" – those will expire and be replaced every few hours. For inbound connections, use the address that *does not* have the "temporary" flag next to it – that one is permanent and can be used in firewall rules, DNS, etc.

Comment: unticking the 'enable firewall service' button on the router let  pings thru after seeing no action initiially from `sudo tcpdump -n -i wlp59s0 ip6|grep 2a03` (where 2a03 was the first part of the pinger's address. ) Next stop, does my cellphone hotspot have some similar firewall?  In any case thanks for the info this was all very helpful.

Comment: Disabling the firewall can be somewhat dangerous, as it makes *all* your LAN devices (computers, printers, TVs, toasters, etc.) reachable from the internet – and many of them aren't exactly known for being well-secured. If the router allows it you should only make it allow access to the specific IP addresses of the computer. As for phone hotspots – yeah, they can certainly have a firewall (if they even support IPv6 sharing at all).

Comment: I did have the sense to retick the firewall after seeing some pings go thru. It looks like the phone has some builtin firewall that I probably won't be able to undo easily , so my ultimate goal of controlling a robot over the net will have to go thru a central server I guess.